# Transpose query creates nodes (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, transpose

I finally found the query to execute to get all ids (comma separated) for one content in one row.

Following query did the trick:

You don't need to look at the query because it already does what it should do.

```
SELECT 
    taxonomy_item_id, 
    SUBSTRING(
      (SELECT ', ' + CAST(taxonomy_id AS varchar) AS Expr1
       FROM taxonomy_item_tbl AS t2
       WHERE (t1.taxonomy_item_id = taxonomy_item_id) AND (taxonomy_language_id = 2067)
       ORDER BY taxonomy_item_id, taxonomy_id FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1000) AS taxonomy_ids
FROM 
    taxonomy_item_tbl AS t1
WHERE 
    (taxonomy_language_id = 2067) AND (taxonomy_item_id = 180555)
GROUP BY 
    taxonomy_item_id
```

The only problem is the data result I get:

```
180555  |   <Expr1>, 404</Expr1><Expr1>, 405</Expr1><Expr1>, 723</Expr1><Expr1>, 1086</Expr1><Expr1>, 1087</Expr1><Expr1>, 1118</Expr1><Expr1>, 1124</Expr1><Expr1>, 1126</Expr1>
```

I don't need the `<Expr1>` nodes. Is there a way to delete this? If I delete `AS Expr1`in the query then it is automatically added back

Thanks

Comment: How are you running this? The `AS Expr1` shouldn't be added back unless you have some query builder in use

Comment: What is a query Builder? Can I disable it?

Comment: I don't know. "How are you running it" I asked...

Comment: -1 for still using a Query Builder and repeating the same mistake  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8486378/27535

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `<Expr1>` - then just don't ask for it!

You have:

```
(SELECT ', ' + CAST(taxonomy_id AS varchar) AS Expr1
```

That `AS Expr1` causes the `<Expr1>` to be added - so just don't have that expression there.

Try

```
SELECT 
    taxonomy_item_id, 
    SUBSTRING(
      (SELECT ', ' + CAST(taxonomy_id AS VARCHAR) 
       FROM dbo.taxonomy_item_tbl AS t2
       WHERE t1.taxonomy_item_id = taxonomy_item_id
       AND taxonomy_language_id = 2067
       ORDER BY taxonomy_item_id, taxonomy_id 
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1000) AS taxonomy_ids
FROM 
    dbo.taxonomy_item_tbl AS t1
WHERE 
    taxonomy_language_id = 2067
    AND taxonomy_item_id = 180555
GROUP BY 
    taxonomy_item_id
```

Comment: I think some Query Builder (MSQuery, Access, whatever) is adding it back in if I understand the question correctly.